# ¿Porqué los links del archivo svg dejan de funcionar si se utiliza un tag img?

Tags: html, svg

## Problema

Tengo un archivo svg que cuenta con un link `<a>` en su interior, la función de este link es ***repetir la animación del svg cada vez que se clica en él***. Funciona correctamente si abro el archivo svg en un navegador, pero al ***importar el archivo en html usando un tag*** `<img>` la animación funciona pero el link no parece ser reconocido ya que al posicionarse sobre el svg el cursor no cambia su default por el pointer y ***al hacer click no se repite la animación***.

Navegadores en los que se verifica esta situación: Firefox, Chrome, Edge.

---

#### Ejemplo mínimo verificable

*Página html*

```
<img src="test.svg" alt="logo">
```

*Archivo svg*

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="680" height="370" viewBox="0 0 180 98">
  <a href="#A" transform="scale(1.7)">
    <rect x="1.5" y="1.5" width="102.6" height="54.3" rx="2.8" fill="#85bb65"/>
    <g>
      <set attributeName="opacity" to="0" dur="2s"/>
      <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="translate" from="40 40" to="0 0" id="A" begin="2s;A.begin" dur="0.5s"/>
      <circle cx="54" cy="29" r="20" fill="#dcdcdc"/>
    </g>
  </a>
</svg>
```

---

#### Enlaces útiles

- [Archivo svg](https://montesariel.com/assets/images/logo-lg.svg) completo que se repite al clicar en él.
- [Sitio web](https://montesariel.com) en el que el archivo es importado con el tag img.

Comment: En Firefox funciona perfecto.

Comment: No en Firefox no funciona. El código no es excesivamente largo; puedes utilizarlo inline. O puedes utilizarlo como `<object>`. Porque quieres utilizarlo como `<img>`?

Comment: Necesito que el svg sea un archivo para que sea cacheable, para poder manipularlo con mayor facilidad y para que esté presente en mi control de versiones.

Comment: @ArielMontes, ¿te podría serviría hacer algo parecido a esto? => `data-src="ruta/archivo.svg"`. Es decir, algo como esto: `<div data-src="ruta/archivo.svg"></div>`

Comment: Amigo, nunca he visto ese atributo en un div. O salió html6 y soy el único despistado o eso que me recomiendas no existe. (Igual lo probé y no funciona)

Comment: Jajaja, no @ArielMontes. Normalmente, es para utilizar la propiedad `dataset`. Por eso, el atributo `data-*` hace referencia al atributo que vayas a crear para utilizarlo con JavaScript.

Comment: Se podría crear un pequeño algoritmo en JavaScript que lea un atributo definido como `data-src` de una forma muy simple. Así tendrías SVG como archivo, a la vez, que lo tienes formando parte del sitio Web. Es muy sencillo el algoritmo. Solo que me gustaría confirmar si te sirve implementarlo así. De ser así, podría explicarlo en una respuesta.

Comment: Si entendí bien, lo que dices es que esa solución iría acompañada de un código js para importar el archivo. Esto no es una opción porque muchos (yo incluido) navegamos con js desactivado.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119273/discussion-between-david-e-luna-m-and-ariel-montes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solución**

Puede deberse a la compatibilidad de navegadores, en Firefox parece ir bien, sin embargo, en Microsoft Edge y Chrome no va usando la etiqueta `<img>`, puedes añadir un `<iframe>` para reemplazar a la etiqueta `<img>`

```html
<iframe src="https://montesariel.com/assets/images/logo-lg.svg"></iframe>
```

Es más eficiente debido a que el `<iframe>` carga la página vinculada en su totalidad

---

**Prueba con la etiqueta img**

Varía dependiendo del navegador, aquí está la misma imagen vinculada con `<img>`

```html
<img src="https://montesariel.com/assets/images/logo-lg.svg" height="300" width="300">
```

Comment: Interesante opción, tendría que editar un poco el iframe para que se ajuste al contenido y quitarle el borde. Pero supongo que funcionará. Me parece curioso que eres la segunda persona en decir que la etiqueta <img> funciona en Firefox, pero he hecho varias pruebas con la última versión y a mi no me funciona.

Comment: Tu solución no es cross browser, <iframe> no es compatible como <img> a través de los navegadores. En chrome se ve bien pero en Firefox es un desastre porque el svg llega a ser mayor que el frame y aparecen los scrolls.